# Attempt at STL Container

Tags: stl, iterator, containers, c++17

I am attempting to make a version of std::set using a linked list. I think I have implemented it mostly correctly but I am getting a compile error that I cannot decipher. I would appreciate anyone spotting the error in my code, and or explaining how I would go about tracking down an error like this. Meaning an error that goes far into stl functions.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
template <typename Type>
struct ListNode{
        Type info;
        ListNode<Type> * next;
        ListNode(Type newInfo, ListNode<Type> * newNext) : info(newInfo), next(newNext){
            }
        ListNode(ListNode<Type>& L): info(L.info), next(L.next){
        }
        ListNode<Type>& operator=(ListNode<Type>& L){
            info = L->info;
            next = L->next;
            return this;
        }
        };
template <typename Type>
class SetList{
    ListNode<Type> * head;
    ListNode<Type> * tail;
       public:
        typedef ListNode<Type> value_type;
        SetList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){
        }
        SetList(SetList & s){

        }
        ~SetList(){
            //ListNode<Type> * cur = head;
            //ListNode<Type> * next = cur;
            //while(cur){
        //      next = cur->next;
        //      delete cur;
        //      cur = next;
          //  }
        }


        struct iterator{
            //traits
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
            typedef iterator self_type;
            typedef Type value_type;
            typedef Type& reference;
            typedef Type* pointer;
            typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
            private:
                //rename to ihead
                ListNode<Type>* ibuf;
            public:
                iterator(ListNode<value_type>* node) : ibuf(node){}
                self_type& operator++(){ibuf = ibuf->next; return *this;}
                self_type operator++(int postfix){
                   self_type cpy = *this;
                   ibuf = ibuf->next;
                   return cpy;
                }
                reference operator*(){return ibuf->info;}
                pointer operator->(){return &ibuf->info;}
                self_type operator=(const iterator& it){insert(*it);}
  bool operator==(const self_type& rhs) const {return ibuf->info == rhs.ibuf->info;}
                bool operator !=(const self_type& rhs) const {return ibuf->info != rhs.ibuf->info;}
        };

        iterator begin(){ return iterator(head);}
        iterator end() { return iterator(nullptr);}
//      const_iterator begin() { return const_iterator(head);}
//      const_iterator end() { return const_iterator(tail);}
        Type operator[](int index){
            iterator cur(head);
            for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i,++cur){
            }
            return *cur;
        }
        SetList<Type>& operator=(const SetList<Type>& s){
            head = s.head;
            tail = s.tail;
            return this;
        }
        iterator find(Type toFind){
            ListNode<Type> * cur = head;
            while(cur){
                if(cur->info == toFind)
                    return iterator(cur);
            }
            return this->end();
        }
        void insert(Type toInsert){
            ListNode<Type>* cur = nullptr;
            if(head){
                cur = new ListNode<Type>(toInsert, head);
                head = cur;
            }else{
                cur = new ListNode<Type>(toInsert, nullptr);
                head = cur;
            }

        }
};
```

I am calling elsewhere copy on my set, my copy call works with std::set but not my set.
The error I am getting is as follows.
[image: error]

Hope this isn't too much to ask. You don't even have to read my code, even just input on how to track down large errors like this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`SetList<Type>` should have `Type` as its `value_type`, not `ListNode<Type>`.